# Can Any one help me how to integrate SAML 2.0 in Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If login in my application it should login in Nimsoft monitoring and Nimsoft service desk.it should not ask for again login.Please give me instructions how to do achieve the single sign in

Is it possible by using SAML 2.0 .Please tell me how to do

Please Reply immediately.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1):

There's a [SAML Omniauth gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-saml) for Rails. I've used it myself for a SAML integration (and even contributed a patch back).

[Omniauth](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth) is a well known Ruby authentication provider. Between the mounds of existing documentation on that, and the pretty good documentation on omniauth-saml you should be good. (Although I'll give you that single sign-on authorization is hard to get your head around the first time you look at it...)